# Error in accessing authserver from resource server with auth server as eureka client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, netflix-eureka

Hi I have a implemented oauth2 service in springboot. Auth-server and resource servers are enabled with eureka client they have successfully registered to eureka server as well. URI for auth-server in resource server is configured this way

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://auth-server/oauth/check_token
```

Now `auth-server` in the above URI is the app name of authserver. I am expecting resource server should contact auth server using `token-info-uri` after it gets url resolved from eureka server. But with this setup I am getting an error `nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: auth-server`

I modified my configuration to this

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      prefer-token-info: false
      service-id: auth-server
      token-info-uri: http://${security.oauth2.resource.service-id}/oauth/check_token
      loadBalanced: true
```

but I am getting response

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "e2f95093-085c-4b59-90a5-c89fb5d1eccb"
}
```

When I debug I have this log

```
asset-mgmt-v1.1_1  | 2019-11-16 17:52:08.048  INFO 1 --- [nio-6001-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 21 ms
asset-mgmt-v1.1_1  | 2019-11-16 17:52:08.086 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-6001-exec-2] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Getting user info from: null
asset-mgmt-v1.1_1  | 2019-11-16 17:52:08.109 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-6001-exec-2] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : HTTP GET 
asset-mgmt-v1.1_1  | 2019-11-16 17:52:08.117 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-6001-exec-2] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
asset-mgmt-v1.1_1  | 2019-11-16 17:52:08.119  WARN 1 --- [nio-6001-exec-2] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Could not fetch user details: class java.lang.IllegalStateException, Request URI does not contain a valid hostname: 
asset-mgmt-v1.1_1  | 2019-11-16 17:52:08.120 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-6001-exec-2] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : userinfo returned error: Could not fetch user details
asset-mgmt-v1.1_1  | 2019-11-16 17:52:08.127 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-6001-exec-2] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-11-16T17:52:08.125Z, principal=access-token, type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException, message=e2f95093-085c-4b59-90a5-c89fb5d1eccb}]
```

Basically URI is picked up is what I see

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use just name in property files. it should be

```
security:
 oauth2:
  resource:
   service-id: {Service ID as at eureka server registered}
   token-info-uri: http://${security.oauth2.resource.service-id}/oauth/check_token
   loadBalanced=true
   prefer-token-info=false
```

P.S I just typed by hand. make sure keep proper spaces

Comment: when you change  ${security.oauth2.resource.service-id} to something else does this error change? this seems it reach oauth server but your credential not been passed.

Answer (score 0):

In the error log presented by Darshu, there is the following message:" asset-mgmt-v1.1_1 | 2019-11-16 17:52:08.120 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-6001-exec-2] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices : userinfo returned error: Could not fetch user details".

The prefer-token-info must be set true to determine that token-info-uri is preferred over user-info-uri.

```
security:
      oauth2:
           resource:
                  prefer-token-info: true
```

See more in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server

Comment: Could you please add some comment/documentation link which would be helpful for people .

Comment: In the error log presented by Darshu, there is the following message:" asset-mgmt-v1.1_1  | 2019-11-16 17:52:08.120 DEBUG 1 --- [nio-6001-exec-2] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : userinfo returned error: Could not fetch user details". The prefer-token-info must be set true to determine that token-info-uri is preferred over user-info-uri. See more in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. What I meant was to edit your answer to give the information that you've given in the comment. That will improve the credibility of your answer. :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a newbie here. I complemented my answer.

Comment: Sure @Davi, we're here to help each other so we just make sure that we do that in the best possible way. Thanks for adding the documentation. Keep helping people.